# Integrate Activiti to JHipster Project

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, activiti, jhipster

I am trying to integrate Activiti to the JHipster Project following the instruction here : [getting started with activiti and spring boot](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot).

a few exception I am facing:

1. conflict in 'userResource' class:

   > Annotation-specified bean name 'userResource' for bean class
   >   [org.activiti.rest.service.api.identity.UserResource]  conflicts with
   >   existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
   >   [com.activiti.demo3.web.rest.UserResource]

For now I have renamed the userResource class that comes from jhipster, but I am not able to figure out the exception below.

2. @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique:

> Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:  @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers
>   must be unique. Order of 100 was already used, so it cannot be used on
>   org.activiti.spring.boot.RestApiAutoConfiguration$SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$320e2174@6b277aed
>   too.

Any suggestion or pointers would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6454

Answer (score 2):

Add `@Order(99)` to the WebConfigurer class that JHipster generated, 99 or any number < 100.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested, but unable to solve the problem. In the `WebConfigurer` Class I had added  `@Order(99)`. Here is my WebConfigurer annotations:

```

/**
 * Configuration of web application with Servlet 3.0 APIs.
 */

@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(CacheConfiguration.class)
@Order(99)

public class WebConfigurer implements ServletContextInitializer, EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebConfigurer.class);
........................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had same issue and I resolved it by
just renaming Jhipster genarated class at
/web/rest/UserResource.java to /web/rest/UserResourceSomethingElse.java

Comment: The original poster mentions in his question that that is exactly what he did to work around this perceived problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have dependencies that may collide. In my case the org.activity:spring-boot-starter-rest-api collide with application. After commenting out:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api</artifactId>
    <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I managed to build my application.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, Add @Order(99) on your websecurity class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.activiti.spring.boot.RestApiAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.onlineBankingApplication"})
@Order(99)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Answer (score -1):

1)

```
@RestController("JhipsterUserResource")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserResource {
```

2) JhcommApp.java

```
import org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

It'll prevent Activiti from adding its own IdentityService to Spring Security.