# Activiti BPM with jHipster project

Tags: spring-boot, activiti, jhipster

Did anyone integrate Activiti BPM with jHipster project? I am trying to do that and facing problems (you can see it in [Integrate Activiti to JHipster Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012786/integrate-activiti-to-jhipster-project)). If anyone can provide any resource for this integration, it will be appreciated. Thanks!